# Read text file containing 2D matrix and associated data

Tags: c++, file, fstream, sstream

I have a text file structured like this:

```
6
0,2,0,0,5,0
3,0,4,0,0,0
0,0,0,6,1,0
0,0,0,0,2,0
0,0,0,0,2,4
1,0,0,0,0,0
0,5
```

The first number represents the number of vertices and the 2D matrix is an adjacency matrix.  The last line contains start and end points.  I understand how to use the data and what its purpose is; what I'm struggling with is properly reading the data so I can process it.  I currently have this:

```
void directedGraphAnalysis() {
    //Open file, read contents, write to graph
    ifstream file("test2a.txt");
    string data     = ""; //Each line will be read as a string and converted to an int
    int nodeCount   = 0;
    int* matrix     = nullptr;
    int matrixIndex = 0;
    int count       = 0;
    int v1          = INT_MAX;
    int v2          = INT_MAX;

    while (getline(file, data, ',')){
        int x = stoi(data);
        ++count;
        if (count == 1) {
            nodeCount = x;
            matrix = new int[nodeCount * nodeCount];
        }
        else if (count < (nodeCount * nodeCount) - 1) {
            matrix[matrixIndex++] = x;
        }
        else if (v1 == INT_MAX) {
            v1 = x;
        }
        else {
            v2 = x;
        }

        cout << "X: " << x << endl;
    }

    //DirectedGraph graph = DirectedGraph(matrix, nodeCount);
    //graph.displayGraph();

    cout << "ANALYSIS COMPLETE." << endl;
}
```

This implementation seems to get the node count right but every line after that skips the first digit, meaning v1 and v2 are never set and the matrix has incorrect edges that don't match with the text file.  Matrix is simply a 1D array representing a 2D matrix of size nodeCount * nodeCount.  I'm not sure what it is I'm doing that's causing the matrix to be improperly filled, nor do I know why the first digits are being skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze your source file and then do input operations as needed.

The adjency matrix seems to be for a directed and weighted graph. It is not clear to me, if it is row or column oriented, but this is not important for the reding operation.

So, would do we see?

1. The dimension as an unsigned interger number on its own line
2. It follows a rectangular matrix with the above given dimension. The rows are given as comma separated values. This, we call CSV. And, there are many many ways to split a csv into its components: BecaUse the matrix is quadratic, there will be *dimension* rows.
3. At the end, we have and additionalline, containing 2 values, the start coordinates, separated by a comma.

Deriving from that observations, we will decide how to read.

The first line can be simply read, with a standard formatted input function, using the extractor operator `>>. Formatted input`will alwaystry toconvert the input data, until it sees a white space (including the newline character '\n'). It will not consume the white space, so the '\n').

The next lines could be written as a whole line using the `std::getline` (unformatted input) function. But caveat. `std::getline` will read, until it finds a newline '\n'. And remember from above, there is still a newline character in theinput stream. So,if you would simply call `std::getline`, it would read an empty string and then consume the new line character. To solve this, we can simply use the [std::ws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) function. This will consume, but not read, all white spaces in front of a text. So, we can always write: `std::getline(file >> std::ws, data);` This will first call `file >> std::ws` and then invoke `std::getline`.

Ok, this theory should be clear now.

Then, we need to create a 2 dimensional array. You are just creating a one dimensional array. This can be done by first creating an array for the rows, and then, for each row, additional arrays for the columns. This wecould do like the below:

```
// allocate memory for rows
int** matrix = new int* [dimension];

// For each row, allocate memory for the columns
for(unsigned int row=0; row < dimension; ++row) 
    matrix[row] = new int [dimension];
```

Now we have a 2d array, which we can address with `matrix[row][col];`

Next, because we do know the dimension, we can create a loop and call `std::getline` *dimension* times.

After having read one line, we need to split that line and store the values. For that we will use one common approach, by using an `std::istringstream` and `std::getline` until we see a comma.

At the end, we read the last line and extract the start coordinates in the same way.

For every read operation an error check should be added.

Then an example program could looklike below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream fileStream{ "r:\\text2a.txt" };

    // Check, if we could open the file
    if (fileStream) {

        // Read the dimension of the matrix and check for valid input
        unsigned int dimension{};
        if ((fileStream >> dimension) and (dimension > 0)) {

            // Now we haveopened the file and read the dimension
            // Allocate array. Firs,allocate memory for rows
            int** matrix = new int* [dimension];

            // And now, for each row, allocate space for columns
            // Then read the rows with the column values
            for (unsigned int row = 0; row < dimension; ++row) {
                matrix[row] = new int[dimension] {};

                // Read next line from file
                std::string line{};
                if (std::getline(fileStream >> std::ws, line)) {

                    // Put the line into an std::istringstream, so that we can extract the column values
                    std::istringstream iss(line);

                    // Extract all columns
                    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < dimension; ++col) {
                        std::string valueAsString{};
                        if (std::getline(iss, valueAsString, ',')) {
                            matrix[row][col] = std::stoi(valueAsString);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Could not read column value. Show error message
                            std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Could not read value at row " << row << ",  column: "<< col << "\n\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Could not read row with column values
                    std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Could not read row number " << row << "\n\n";
                }
            }
            // Now we have read the matrix. 
            // Get the start point
            unsigned int rowStart{}, columnStart{};
            char comma{};
            if ((fileStream >> rowStart >> comma >> columnStart) and comma == ',') {


                // Now, we have all data
                // Show some debug output
                std::cout << "Adjancency matrix\n\nDimension: " << dimension << "\n\nMatrix:\n\n";

                for (unsigned int row = 0; row < dimension; ++row) {
                    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < dimension; ++col) {
                        std::cout << matrix[row][col] << ' ';
                    }
                    std::cout << '\n';
                }
                std::cout << "\n\nStart point: " << rowStart << ", " << columnStart << '\n';


                // Release all allocated memory
                for (unsigned int row = 0; row < dimension; ++row)
                    delete[] matrix[row];
                delete[] matrix;
            }
            else {
                // Could not read start values
                std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not read start values\n\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            // Invalid input for dimension of adjacency matrix. Show error message
            std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Invalid dimentsion found\n\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        // File could not be opened. Show error message
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Could not open source file\n\n";
    }
}
```